# Unable to install Rstudio after reinstalling R

Tags: openssl, r, rstudio

Rstudio showed me a newer version, so I downloaded and installed it, but it refused to start afterwards, I removed and reinstalled R and Rstudio, the error persists. This is the error it gives me:

````
## R Session Startup Failure Report

### RStudio Version

RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom " (3c53477a, 2023-03-09) for Ubuntu Bionic

Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) rstudio/2023.03.0+386 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

### Error message

[No error available]

### Process Output

The R session exited with code 1. 

Error output:

```
/usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/rsession: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1: version `OPENSSL_1_1_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/rstudio/resources/app/bin/rsession)

```

Standard output:

```
[No output emitted]
```

### Logs

*/home/saidm/.local/share/rstudio/log/rsession-saidm.log*

```
2023-04-10T12:51:15.085762Z [rsession-saidm] ERROR asio.netdb error 1 (Host not found (authoritative)); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(rstudio::core::http::SocketAcceptorService<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, const string&, const string&) src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:88; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2267
2023-04-10T13:03:12.607866Z [rsession-saidm] ERROR asio.netdb error 1 (Host not found (authoritative)); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(rstudio::core::http::SocketAcceptorService<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, const string&, const string&) src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:88; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2267
2023-04-10T13:03:12.607866Z [rsession-saidm] ERROR asio.netdb error 1 (Host not found (authoritative)); OCCURRED AT rstudio::core::Error rstudio::core::http::initTcpIpAcceptor(rstudio::core::http::SocketAcceptorService<rstudio_boost::asio::ip::tcp>&, const string&, const string&) src/cpp/session/http/SessionPosixHttpConnectionListener.cpp:88; LOGGED FROM: int main(int, char* const*) src/cpp/session/SessionMain.cpp:2267

```
````

I also checked whether I have `openssl 1.1.1` in my computer and it seems to be the case.

```
OpenSSL 1.1.1q  5 Jul 2022
built on: Mon Jul 11 14:52:57 2022 UTC
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) rc4(16x,int) des(int) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: /opt/conda/conda-bld/openssl_1657551138854/_build_env/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-cc -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/saidm/anaconda3/include -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/saidm/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/conda/conda-bld/openssl_1657551138854/work=/usr/local/src/conda/openssl-1.1.1q -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/saidm/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -Wa,--noexecstack -fPIC -pthread -m64 -Wa,--noexecstack -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /home/saidm/anaconda3/include -fdebug-prefix-map=/opt/conda/conda-bld/openssl_1657551138854/work=/usr/local/src/conda/openssl-1.1.1q -fdebug-prefix-map=/home/saidm/anaconda3=/usr/local/src/conda-prefix -Wa,--noexecstack -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DL_ENDIAN -DOPENSSL_PIC -DOPENSSL_CPUID_OBJ -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DKECCAK1600_ASM -DRC4_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAESNI_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DGHASH_ASM -DECP_NISTZ256_ASM -DX25519_ASM -DPOLY1305_ASM -DNDEBUG -DNDEBUG -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2 -isystem /home/saidm/anaconda3/include
OPENSSLDIR: "/home/saidm/anaconda3/ssl"
ENGINESDIR: "/home/saidm/anaconda3/lib/engines-1.1"
Seeding source: os-specific
```

Therefore, can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong? I work a lot with `R` and I need to fix this problem as soon as possible. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS.

Comment: You have openssl in the conda environment which might not be available for rstudio. I would recommend to install the lastest openssl in the system

Comment: @llrs thank you.